# Old layout shown over with new activity

Tags: android

I have an APK that runs completely fine across several android levels varying from android 5 through 9. We started testing a new android 9 phone (Hot Pepper HPP-L55B aka Serrano), and I'm seeing an interesting issue that I'm hoping someone has come across.

All of my Activities extend a base activity that does some standard logging (such as logging onCreate, onResume, etc).

On app launch:
Activity 1 - MainLaunch

- onCreate starts the activity Splash then calls finish

Activity 2 - Splash

- onCreate sets the content view and finds the WebView on the screen.
- onResume sets a gif in the webview so it's rendered on the splash screen.  It also starts a thread that sleeps for a few seconds that then kicks off Activity 3.  The gif animates as expected.

Activity 3 - Launchpad

- onCreate sets the content view and finds references to other items on the screen (buttons and textviews).
- onResume checks a few internal things, and may or may not hide things on the UI based on configuration. Nothing to exciting.

There are times this process will go through without a hitch, and other times where the UI that was being displayed in Activity 2 (splash) stays up while my logs are showing that the code thinks it's showing UI 3.  The gif in this case is no longer animating.

As you click around on the splash screen the buttons that are referenced and would be showing on Activity 3 are being pressed. So basically like the splash screen is covering the 3rd activities screen and allowing button push pass through.  If i turn the screen off/on again the splash screen still shows up.  Throwing breakpoints in activity 3 get hit as the hidden buttons get clicked.

Anyone ever see this before or have suggestions how to fix it?  This phone model seems to be the only one with the issue.  So it definitely seems like a phone model problem and not anything i can control.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem boiled down to the processor (MediaTek) being used in combination with the theme being used for the application.  At least that was the only thing that was found different across the supported phones we tested.

The theme for the activities were changed:

from @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
to @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar